# Instance variables are the same in each object initialization

Tags: java, arrays, member, instance-variables

I'm making a genetic algorithm that deals with evolving an array of `char`s into "Hello World". The problem is whenever I initialize a `Chromosome` object and call the `generateChromosome` method, all the chromosomes of "test" population remains the same?

```
public class Chromosome{
   private static int defaultLength = 11;
   private static char []genes = new char[defaultLength]; <--- this remains the same for each object :/


   //Generates a random char chromosome
   public void generateChromosome(){
      char []newGene =  new char[defaultLength];
      for(int x = 0; x<size(); x++){
         char gene = (char)(32+Math.round(96*Math.random()));
         newGene[x] = gene;

      }
      genes = newGene;

   }

   //Returns a specific gene in the chromosome
   public char getGene(int index){
     return genes[index];
   }

   public char[] getChromosome(){
      return genes;
   }

   public void setGene(char value, int index){

   genes[index] = value;

   }

   public static  void setDefaultLength(int amount){
      defaultLength = amount;
   }

   public static int getDefaultLength(){
      return defaultLength;
   }

   public int size(){
      return genes.length;
   }

   @Override
   public String toString(){
      String geneString = "";
      for(int x= 0; x<genes.length; x++){
         geneString += genes[x];
      }
      return geneString;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`static` means one per class (not one per instance). Remove the `static`

```
private char[] genes = new char[defaultLength];
```

and your `genes` becomes an instance field.

Comment: 0.o when I did that and gave it a test run on main class, this appeared for all chromosomes. 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000

Comment: Sounds like you didn't run `generateChromosome()`.

Comment: nope I did, strange because making it a class variable does work even if it's value is limited to the class.

Comment: public class GA{  public static void main(String[] args){  
      Population test = new Population(10);  
      FitnessCalc.setSolution("Hello World");  
      
      for(int x = 0; x<test.size();x++){  
         System.out.println(test.getChromosome(x));  
      }  
   }

Comment: You aren't calling `generateChromosome()` unless it's in `Population`. And please [**edit**](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27683357/edit) your question.

Comment: generateChromosome is called when you initialize a population.

Comment: If you get all `0`(s) out then it isn't called correctly. I can't tell you what is wrong without seeing it.

Comment: He is re - assigning the reference 'gene' so the values will be default

Comment: @TheLostMind Appears to `newGene` (which is populated). At least in the posted code. Who knows what's going on the in the `Population` constructor.

Comment: Ok so I removed newGene and reassigned the value to genes, looks like it worked! Thanks for help!

Answer (score 3):

That's because your variables are `static`, i.e. class variables. They will be the same in each instantiation of your class.

If you want an instance variable, remove the static keyword.

Answer (score 2):

`static` members belong to the **class** - they are shared across all its instances. You should define `genes` as an instance member by removing the `static` keyword:

```
public class Chromosome{
   private static int defaultLength = 11; // should probably be final, BTW
   private char[] genes = new char[defaultLength]; // not static!
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using `static` keyword in genes it is not an instance variable. Therefore though you assigned the created array to it, there will be **only one instance through out the application**.

You cam remove the static keyword and uses instance gene variable.

Answer (score 1):

Make `genes` as **instance variable** by removing `static` keyword.
Because,

1) `static` means **one per class**

2) `instance` means **one per instance**

For more information on `static`, 
see https://stackoverflow.com/a/413904/2127125